# read out relative weight of server in RDP farm

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

We have several Windows 2008 RDP servers organized in a farm. Is there an easy ways to *remotely* read out each servers relative weight in the farm? (The setting configurable in `tsconfig.msc`, in section "Configure settings", under heading "Remote desktop session broker", on entry "meber of farm in remote desktop connecton broker", right-click "propreties", on "remote desktop connection broker" property sheet, setting "relative weight of server in the farm" (all labels translated from German, so possibly not accurate)

One way would be to access the registry (HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\ClusterSettings\ServerWeight), but I wonder if there is something nicer (for whatever definition of nice).

Comment: Batch file + `reg query`, or perhaps PowerShell.

Comment: Import-Module RemoteDesktopServices

cd rds:\RDSConfiguration\ConnectionBrokerSettings

dir